# How to Define Generic “Invalid“ Values for Different Types

Tags: swift, generics

In my app, I am using Integers, Doubles, Floats, and CGFloats to represent a number of different values. According to my app’s semantic, these values may become “invalid“, a state which I represent using a reserved value, i. e. `-1`. The simplest approach to make this usable in code would be this:

```
anIntVariable = -1
aFloatVariable = -1
aDoubleVariable = -1.0
...
```

To get away from this convention driven approach and increase readability and adaptability I defined a number of extensions:

```
extension Int {
    static var invalid = -1
}
extension Float {
    static var invalid = -1.0
}
extension Double {
    static var invalid = -1.0
}
...
```

So the above code would now read:

```
anIntVariable = .invalid
aFloatVariable = .invalid
aDoubleVariable = .invalid
...
```

It does work. However, I’m not really happy with this approach. Does anyone of you have an idea for a better way of expressing this?

To add some complexity, in addition to simple types like `Int`, `Float`, or `Double`, I also use `Measurement` based types like this:

```
let length = Measurement(value: .invalid, unit: UnitLength.baseUnit())
```

Extra bonus point if you find a way to include “invalid“ measurements in your solution as well...

Thanks for helping!

---

**Some Additional Thoughts**

I know I could use optionals with `nil` meaning “invalid”. In this case, however, you’d have additional overhead with conditional unwrapping... Also, using `nil` as “invalid” is yet another convention.

It isn’t better or worse, just different. Apple uses “invalid” values in its own APIs, i. e. the `NSTableView`method `row(for:)` will return `-1` if the view is not in the table view. I agree, however, that this very method perfectly illustrates that returning an optional would make a lot of sense...

Comment: `1 + .invalid =  0`operations with `.invalid` are still possible. What do you expect from `.invalid`?

Comment: Can you use `nil` for invalid values?

Comment: I think the first question would be what do you need an invalid value for.

Comment: @All: Thanks for your comments. While you add to this question I more and more feel I should try to switch to optionals... Will give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use optionals for that.

If you want lack of value and invalid value to be different states in your app, i'd suggest creating a wrapper for your values:

```
enum Validatable<T> {
   case valid(T)
   case invalid
}
```

And use it like that:

```
let validValue : Validatable<Int> = .valid(5)
let invalidValue : Validatable<Int> = .invalid

var validOptionalDouble : Validatable<Double?> = .valid(nil)
validOptionalDouble = .valid(5.0)

let measurement : Validatable<Measurement> = .invalid
```

etc.

You can then check for value by switch on that enum to access the associated value like this:

```
switch validatableValue {
case .valid(let value):
    //do something with value
case .invalid:
    //handle invalid state
}
```

or

```
if case .valid(let value) = validatableValue {
    //handle valid state
}
```

etc

Comment: Thanks a lot, @FruitAddict. All points achieved, even the bonuses... I will still have to think about using optionals as an alternative. Not sure yet which is the better approach.

Comment: It all depends on one thing - is lack of value (nil) a valid state in your use case? Optionals are enums too under the hood. They have 2 cases (some and none). You could treat none (nil) as your invalid state. But you can't really have a state where a variable is present and is invalid at the same time this way.

Comment: How is that differs from optionals? :)

Comment: It wraps the value so nil case of optional can still be a valid value in authors use case (for example lets say you have a height measurement form in your app. Lack of it can be a valid state - user doesn't have to input the measurement if he doesn't want to. However if he enters -200 as his height, it's invalid)